# Unix Email shell script not getting the To: from email

Tags: email, unix

Hi I wrote a shell script. This shell script sends my file.html file out. Everything is great but it seems when I receive the file it does not have a To : address. For example it would look like this instead of this.

```
**Looks like this** 
Report
To :
Body : TONS OF INFO HERE.

**Want it to look like this in email**
Report
To: Bob@aol.com
Body : TONS OF INFO HERE.

My Script 
    #!/bash/bash
    Email()
    {
    export MAILTO="bob@aol.com"
    export CONTENT="File.html"
    export SUBJECT="Report"
    (
     echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
     echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
     echo "Content-Type: text/html"
     echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
     cat $CONTENT
    ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
    }

    Email
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MAILTO='bob@aol.com'
```

or

```
MAILTO="bob\@aol.com"
```

The `@` character indicates an array variable in bash, and `@` characters in double-quote marks are expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding another `echo` to separate the contents from the header:

```
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
echo
```

Also quote your variables well to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.

```
cat "$CONTENT"
/usr/sbin/sendmail "$MAILTO"
```

Comment: @user3794531 Perhaps you need to explicitly specify the `To:` header as well: `echo "To: $MAILTO"`. And perhaps use `sendmail -t`.

Comment: Consider adding `From:` header too if it doesn't work.